type 1 FIR filter formulation on SMT solver z3
I have a project that I am currently stuck on. I am trying to find the filter coefficients for a Type 1 FIR filter (even filter order and symetrical) using Z3 with the Python API, but the results I get do not meet the constraints I provided to the solver.
For the input to the solver, I specified some magnitude upper bounds and lower bounds for various frequencies, along with the filter order. The formulation for the problem is as follows:
$$
\left| H(e^{j\omega}) \right|=\sum_{m=0}^{({N/2})}h(m)\cdot cos(m\omega), \forall \omega\in \Omega_{d}
$$
where $\Omega_{d}$ represents the discretized frequencies in the range $\Omega_{d} \in \left[0, \pi \right]$, $h(m)$ the filter coefficient and $N$ is the filter order.
I discretized the frequency range, substituted these frequencies into the equation, and constrained the results using the upper and lower magnitude bounds for each discretized frequency.
$$
lowerbound(\omega)\le\left| H(e^{j\omega}) \right|\le upperbound(\omega)
$$

As you can see, the FFT of the resulting coefficients should lie within the bounds (red for upper and blue for lower), but unfortunately, it does not. I have been stuck on this problem for several days. So, any input would be really appreciated.
My project is derived from this paper here:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337855893_Design_of_Optimal_Multiplierless_FIR_Filters
I fitted my code to to this testbench here:
https://pastebin.com/QCTdbdz4

Before starting the debug effort, did you base your code on porting the open-source C++ implementation of the proposed methods that the authors made available? https://gitlab.com/filteropt/firopt

wait, Z3 can be used for optimization problems? didn't know that! Thought it was just solving systems of constraints or proving them unsolvable, not finding an optimal solution. Interesting!

@Stephen I did, but he did FIRopt with ilp and i am trying to do it on z3. Also, the way he done his frequency part in his code is really confusing to me.

@MarcusMüller you can do it with optimize() but its really slow, the way i want to do it is just run a loop from the worst to the best constraint and find where it is satisfiable. Then take that result.

@Ludwig I mean, not to criitcize your methodology, but the search space here is infiinite

I haven't checked your code in detail, but there are at least two fundamental issues that I can see from your problem formulation:

the coefficients $h(m)$ in your equation are not the FIR filter taps that you need as input for the FFT to compute the frequency response.

your equation for the magnitude of the frequency response is actually NOT the magnitude, but the bipolar amplitude function. Consequently, you need a symmetrical bound in the stopband. If $\delta_s$ is the maximal (linear) deviation from zero in the stopband, then the constraint on the amplitude function must be $+\delta_s$ and $-\delta_s$ in the stopband.


I don't know Z3 or how you use it, but what I can tell you is that providing constraints on the amplitude function can result in two things: either there's no solution (if the constraints are too stringent), or there are infinitely many solutions. This means that just providing constraints is not enough to design a filter. You also need to minimize some error measure, subject to the given constraints.

You are correct. I need to flip the coefficients first because $h(0)$ is the middle frequency for type 1 filter, then mirror the resulting coefficients. Thank you for pointing that out. I will work on that error measure once I am done with the baseline. Once again thank you very much.

After discussing with my supervisor, I found where I went wrong with the formulation. I misunderstood what was meant by odd and even filter order. I thought an even-order filter meant there was no middle filter coefficient, but this was incorrect. For clarification, the filter coefficient is the number of registers in a filter design. After revising the code, here is the correct formulation:
https://pastebin.com/jvwUkKBP
Thank you, everyone, for taking the time to help me out. Unfortunately, I cannot close this post for some reason, i think my account has a synchronization issue.
